# Powsershell reading server list from a text file

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with powershell reading my servers from a text file. When I declare a variable with get-content but when i call it, powershell doesnt read the server names. Here is the code.

```
$Server = Get-Content C:\servers.txt

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System -ComputerName $Server |
  Select-Object @{Name = “ComputerName”; Expression = {$_.__SERVER}},
@{Name = “SystemUpTime”; Expression = {New-TimeSpan -Seconds $_.SystemUpTime}}| Export-CSV C:\test2.txt.
```

If I change the $server to the list form It will work. Any ideas?

Comment: "powershell doesnt read the server names"  I don't know what that means.    "If I change the $server to the list form"  I don't know what that means, either.

Comment: Don't you have to splat your server list? $server = @(Get-Content C:\servers.txt). The "-ComputerName" expects a single name or an array of names.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code so the servers are an array and its working now